# What is the ideal time for free connection in transaction which is not commit or rollback in PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, transactions, sequelize.js

**What is the ideal time for free connection in transaction which is not commit or rollback in PostgreSQL?**
In node js I fire query using sequelizejs  ORM. Each query in transaction open new connection with database server. It hold connection until that transaction commit or rollback. If in case I forgot to commit or rollback transaction then it not 
release connection after some time it go into dead lock state.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal time is zero.

The shorter transactions are, the less burden they create on the database system, because they do not hold locks and keep deleted row versions from being reclaimed.

You should not have idle connections with open transactions.

Comment: you may be right but  my connection hang for some time and  i am not able to figure out that time.

Comment: That may be so, but that's not ideal (which is what you asked for in your question). It's no problem to have an idle connection, only to have an idle connection with an open transaction.